Longitudial profile of a lake in matplotlib
I have a script in python for temperature visualisation. Input data are something like this:
imported excel table 
I have this code, it works fine:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# import data from excel file
df = pd.read_excel('temperature_data.xlsx', index_col=0)

# Assign columns to variables
places = df.columns
depth = df.index
temperature = np.ma.masked_invalid(df.to_numpy())

# Creating the graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
min_temp = temperature.min()
max_temp = temperature.max()
cs = plt.contourf(places, depth, temperature, cmap='coolwarm', vmin=min_temp, vmax=max_temp)
cs2 = plt.contour(places, depth, temperature, levels=range(round(min_temp), round(max_temp)+1, 1), colors='black')
plt.clabel(cs2, inline=1, fontsize=10, fmt='%d')
plt.title('Teplota vody [°C]')

#plt.xlabel('Places')
plt.ylabel('hloubka [m]')
plt.colorbar(cs, cmap='coolwarm')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()

But I want the visualisation with the smooth contours and the bottom line. Something like this:
desired output
Can you help me, please? Thank you very much, Dušan.
I've tried to write an included script.

"I've tried to write an included script." -- What was the script you tried?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to SO. In the future, do not post images of your data. People do not have the patience to reproduce it by hand. Instead, do df.to_dict() and post the output. Also, spend some time elaborating your question.

You can do this this way. First ocnvert your dataframe from wide format to long format using melt to facilitate manipulation. Remove all None adn extract the profile number from the profile name and convert it to an int for plotting. Then create a grid for interpolation using meshgrid and interpolate the temperatures onto this grid using griddata using a cubic interpolation. Fianlly, mask any nan values in the interpolated grid to avoid plotting issues. And plot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

data = {
    'profile 1': [22.6, 22.6, 22.5, 22.5, 22.4, 22.4, 22.3, 22.3, 21.7, 21.6, 21.6, 21.6, 21.6, 21.4, 21.2, 21.0, 19.5],
    'profile 2': [22.6, 22.6, 22.6, 22.5, 22.4, 22.3, 22.1, 21.8, 21.7, 21.7, 21.6, 21.6, 21.6, 21.1, 20.6, None, None],
    'profile 3': [22.6, 22.6, 22.3, 22.3, 22.2, 22.1, 22.0, 21.8, 21.7, 21.7, 21.6, 21.5, 21.4, 21.1, 20.6, 21.0, None],
    'profile 4': [22.5, 22.4, 21.7, 21.7, 21.0, 18.7, 18.5, 18.3, 18.3, 18.3, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    'profile 5': [22.1, 22.1, 21.7, 21.7, 21.0, 16.8, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    'profile 6': [20.9, 20.9, 19.8, 19.8, 16.8, 16.8, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    'profile 7': [15.5, 15.2, 15.6, 15.6, 15.7, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
}

depth = list(range(17))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=depth)

df_long = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index'])
df_long.columns = ['depth', 'profile', 'temperature']

df_long = df_long.dropna()

df_long['profile_num'] = df_long['profile'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int) - 1

grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(df_long['profile_num'].min(), df_long['profile_num'].max(), 200), 
                             np.linspace(df_long['depth'].min(), df_long['depth'].max(), 200))
grid_z = griddata((df_long['profile_num'], df_long['depth']), df_long['temperature'], (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

grid_z = np.ma.masked_invalid(grid_z)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
min_temp = np.nanmin(grid_z)
max_temp = np.nanmax(grid_z)
cs = ax.contourf(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, cmap='coolwarm', vmin=min_temp, vmax=max_temp)
cs2 = ax.contour(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, levels=np.arange(int(min_temp), int(max_temp)+1), colors='black')
ax.clabel(cs2, inline=1, fontsize=10, fmt='%d')
ax.set_title('Teplota vody [°C]')
ax.set_xlabel('R. km')
ax.set_ylabel('Hloubka (m n.m.)')
fig.colorbar(cs, ax=ax, cmap='coolwarm')
ax.invert_yaxis()

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)

plt.show()

which will give you

